# Sorting a list of numeric strings with numerous decimal points

Tags: c#, sorting

I've got a situation where I need to sort a list of strings that contain three decimal parts in descending order from left-to-right. The real code is a dictionary of `<string, object>`, but I've simplified it here as I'm in the same predicament either way.

Straight to the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> perlVersions = new List<string>();

        perlVersions.Add("5.26.1_32");
        perlVersions.Add("5.24.1_32");
        perlVersions.Add("5.8.1_64");
        perlVersions.Add("5.24.2_64");

        perlVersions.Sort();
        perlVersions.Reverse();
        foreach (string str in perlVersions) Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5.8.1_64
5.26.1_32
5.24.2_64
5.24.1_32
```

Now, Everything works well, except that the `5.8.1_64`, due to the second part of the number being lower than all others, should be at the bottom.

Is there a special sorting trick I'm missing, or is there a way to further break apart the strings and sort on each individual element?

Comment: you'll probably need to implement your own IComparer, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx .. you can use the Version class to sort everything prior to the "_", then use int comparison for what's after the "_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example split the `string` and treat the different parts an integers, and then sort by these using some LINQ:

```
static void Main()
{
    List<string> perlVersions = new List<string>();

    perlVersions.Add("5.26.1_32");
    perlVersions.Add("5.24.1_32");
    perlVersions.Add("5.8.1_64");
    perlVersions.Add("5.24.2_64");

    perlVersions = perlVersions
        .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '.' }))
        .Select(x =>
        {
            string[] lastParts = x[2].Split(new char[] { '_' });
            return new { a = Convert.ToInt32(x[0]), b = Convert.ToInt32(x[1]), c = Convert.ToInt32(lastParts[0]), d = Convert.ToInt32(lastParts[1]) };
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.a).ThenBy(x => x.b).ThenBy(x => x.c).ThenBy(x => x.d)
        .Select(x => string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}_{3}", x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d))
        .ToList();

    perlVersions.Reverse();
    foreach (string str in perlVersions) Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, and even takes the underscore into consideration. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
string[] separator = new string[] { "." };  
var result = perlVersions
   .OrderByDescending(s => int.Parse(s.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]))
   .OrderByDescending(s => int.Parse(s.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. This is nice and concise, which I like, and I'm definitely going with it. With this code, it should be trivial for me to break apart the last section with the underscore, and sort on the first half of that part (ie 2_32). Cheers!

Comment: You did indeed @mm8! Answers were flying in so quickly, I missed it. I'm sorry to Marusyk here, but due to the underscore piece taken care of, I've had to change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or a fully query syntax version:

```
var b = from v in perlVersions
        let ii = v.Split(".")
                  .Take(2)
                  .Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToArray()
        orderby ii[0] descending
        orderby ii[1] descending
        select v;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do you custom sort using Linq
To do so split your string by '.' and then extend each part with '0'

```
List<string> perlVersions = new List<string>();

perlVersions.Add("5.26.1_32");
perlVersions.Add("5.24.1_32");
perlVersions.Add("5.8.1_64");
perlVersions.Add("5.24.2_64");

perlVersions = perlVersions
    .OrderByDescending(v => string.Concat(v.Split('.').Select(x => x.PadLeft(5, '0'))))
    .ToList();
```

This will (temporary) convert "8" to "00008" and "24" to "00024", which make your sort working as expected.